# Repeat node type using XSLT without sequence

Tags: xml, model, xsd

I use Relax NG to control an XML template. I would like to make two nodes repeatable and swap them in the XML template. To make my XML file conform to this :

```
    <root>
        <node>
            <variableValueElement>first node type</variableValueElement>
            <fixedValueElement>Value1</fixedValueElement> 
        </node>
        <node>
            <variableValueElement>first node type</variableValueElement>
            <fixedValueElement>Value1</fixedValueElement> 
        </node>
        <node>
            <variableValueElement>second node type</variableValueElement>
            <fixedValueElement>Value2</fixedValueElement> 
        </node>
        <node>
            <variableValueElement>first node type</variableValueElement>
            <fixedValueElement>Value1</fixedValueElement> 
        </node>
    </root>
```

For this, I prepared the following RNG file:

```
<rng:start>
        <rng:element name="root">
                <rng:oneOrMore>
                    <rng:element name="node">
                        <rng:element name="variableValueElement">
                            <rng:data type="string"/>
                        </rng:element>
                        <rng:element name="fixedValueElement">
                            <rng:value type="string">Value1</rng:value>
                        </rng:element>
                    </rng:element>
                </rng:oneOrMore>
                <rng:oneOrMore>
                    <rng:element name="node">
                        <rng:element name="variableValueElement">
                            <rng:data type="string"/>
                        </rng:element>
                        <rng:element name="fixedValueElement">
                            <rng:value type="string">Value2</rng:value>
                        </rng:element>
                    </rng:element>
                </rng:oneOrMore>
        </rng:element>
    </rng:start>
```

If I add a node with fidexValueElement = Value1 after a node with fixedValueElement = Value2, I get an error. Can we represent this kind of case in RNG? Thank you!

Comment: Why does the question's title mention "XSLT"?

Comment: Can you describe the constraints in plain English? You want to allow different types of `node` elements, in any order? Or only at least one `node` with `fixedValue` element being `Value1` followed by an optional number of `Value2` `node`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your instance is valid against the schema

```
<grammar xmlns="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"
    xmlns:a="http://relaxng.org/ns/compatibility/annotations/1.0"
    datatypeLibrary="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes">
    <start>
        <element name="root">
            <oneOrMore>
                <oneOrMore>
                    <element name="node">
                        <element name="variableValueElement">
                            <data type="string"/>
                        </element>
                        <element name="fixedValueElement">
                            <value type="string">Value1</value>
                        </element>
                    </element>
                </oneOrMore>
                <zeroOrMore>
                    <element name="node">
                        <element name="variableValueElement">
                            <data type="string"/>
                        </element>
                        <element name="fixedValueElement">
                            <value type="string">Value2</value>
                        </element>
                    </element>
                </zeroOrMore>
            </oneOrMore>
        </element>
    </start>
</grammar>
```

I am not sure, however, you want to allow the zero existence of

```
<node>
    <variableValueElement>second node type</variableValueElement>
    <fixedValueElement>Value2</fixedValueElement> 
</node>
```